# Joining tables and comparing IDs in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, razor, webmatrix

I have tried everything but this is just not working, I am grabbing the ID from one database (RMS) and comparing that ID to another database called RMSposts. I want it to look like the picture when for example:

```
TABLE RMS
ID: 100

TABLE RMSposts
PostID:100
Notes: sdsdfgsdfg
PostID: 100
Notes: dsfgsdfg
PostID: 99
Notes: blabla
```

So if I click on case 100 only the Notes for case 100 show

[image: this is working with the actual ID# entered in the Select statement]

This code only works when I plug in the number manually, but I want to use razor syntax to call up the ID of the case I am looking at. Could someone help please? I have not been able to figure this out!

```
@{     
string IDp=Request["ID"]; 
var query = ("SELECT * FROM RMSposts WHERE PostID=@0");
var data2 = db.QuerySingle(query, UrlData[0]);
{foreach(var row in db.Query("Select * FROM RMSposts WHERE PostID=100")){   
if (data2 != null) { 
@row.Notes<br>
@Name<br>
@row.Updated<Br><hr>
 }else {
    <div>----There are no previous entries----</div><br>
}
}}}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you change the sql tag that I added, so that it indicates which database you are using. MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: @DOK its on the title

Comment: SQL is just a language used by many databases. If you can specify which particular database you are using, you will attract the attention of more experts in your particular database type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I haven't understood what you want to accomplish.

The following code should display your data:

```
@{
    string param = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UrlData[0]) ? "0": UrlData[0]);
    var db = Database.Open("yourDb");
    var query = "SELECT * FROM RMSposts WHERE PostID = @0";
    var data = db.Query(query, param);
}

<div>
    @if (data != null)
    {
        foreach(var row in data)
        {
            <p>@row.Notes<br>@Name<br>@row.Updated<br><hr></p>
        }
    } else {
        <div>----There are no previous entries----</div><br>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: data will never be null. You should use Any() instead.